# Deleting an item somewhere in a vector of structs

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have a vector that is filled with structs. The struct looks something like this:

```
struct entry{
    int something
    int something2;
    int LRU; // least recently used
};
```

What I want to do is to first find the struct in the vector that has the lowest LRU. And tried doing this by:

```
least = vector[0].LRU; 
for (entry &e : vector ) {
    if (e.LRU < least)
    least = e.LRU; 
}
```

Is this something that would work? And how do I now delete the right struct in the TLB?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `std::min_element()` with a lambda + `std::vector::erase()`

Comment: Can you explain what's stopping you from trying to see if it works, and gives the correct results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be to make sure that the element with the lowest `LRU` is last in `vector` using [`std::nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element). You can then just `resize()` `vector` to get rid of the last element.

Example:

```cpp
if(not vector.empty()) {
    std::nth_element(vector.begin(), std::prev(vector.end()), vector.end(),
        [](auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs) {
            return rhs.LRU < lhs.LRU;
        });
    vector.resize(vector.size() - 1);
}
```

Another way is to use [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) to get an iterator to the `entry` with the lowest `LRU` and then call `vector.erase()` with that iterator.

```
if(not vector.empty()) {
    auto it = std::min_element(vector.begin(), vector.end(),
        [](auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs) {
            return lhs.LRU < rhs.LRU;
        });
    vector.erase(it);
}
```